# A Mobile Phone App API without these limitations

Tags: android, ios, mobile, mobile-phones

**I have been developing Mobile phone apps in Mosync(Cross Platform C++ API - can make apps in iOS, Android, Symbian & Blackberry) & I am looking to develop apps in something else because of the limitations of Mosync.**

But I dont want to move to a different API to find they have the same or worse limitations. I am thinking of moving to native API's (iOS or Android) but am open to other cross platform API's aswell.

If I was to move to Android OR iOS OR **insert API here** would I experience these limitations:

- Resizing images is expensive(in terms of RAM & speed). IE, so can Android, iOS handle resizing 10+ images(for eg .png) & display them on screen in a relatively fast amt of time? In Mosync doing such stuff depends on the phone RAM but on HTC Desire(512mb) it takes about 6 seconds which is unacceptable for my app.
- Does the API come with its own fonts & layout managers? Mosync doesn't have its own fonts, you have to create & import it & you cant change the colour of a font. You also cannot make the text in a widget display centred or word wrapped, can Android/iOS/other do this?
- Can you create your own skins(.png) for buttons(any widget) & set a default API button's skin? This is actually a strength of Mosync where you can change button skins BUT it divides the skin up into 9 sections & only the 5th section is scalable, the others stay the same size, so on small phones a lrg skin looks weird.
- Is it a REAL headache designing your app layout because of all the different potential phone sizes there are, so the widgets placement & skins will be incorrect on small screens & images will be out of proportion on large screens? Does the Android/iOS/other API help you by automatically laying out your GUI no matter the phone size & does it automatically scale image widgets & fonts to suit phone sizes?

**Any info would be really helpful to a Junior programmer(intern) who is developing mobile apps all on his own & finding the myriad of phone sizes so ANNOYING to compensate for**

Comment: I notice that the native font availability is on the mosync roadmap, also they have a nativeUI framework now.
Fragmentation will always exist, it just needs to be made managable.  MadeWithMarmalade is another SDK.  But remember, MoSync is one of the few that can target J2ME as well if that's an important consideration.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with Android Code:

- Image resizing - Many current android apps seem to meet your
  performance requirements although you don't mention the size of the
  images which is the key issue.
- Android supports many fonts internally, allows full control of font size, type face, colour etc
- Android supports a complex variety of 'Drawables' including standard simple
  graphics, 9-patch pngs (similar to what you describe) and simple vector descriptions of shapes and colours.
- Android was designed with the difficulties of multiple screen sizes in mind; It supports multiple layouts for different screens sizes and orientations. This problem is intrinsically difficult and imho Android takes a lot of the trouble out the process - but it is always going to be a little bit of headache.

I am just reaching production on my first serious android app and have found the development experience pleasant and the learning curve easy.